# How to customize checkout success page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, order-success-page

We want to add this text
"Click here to check the bank information" to the checkout success page and link it with URL a on the site.

How to do that?

We're running Magento 1.9

Answer (score 5):

- Check whether there is **`success.phtml`** file in **app/design/frontend/yourthemepackage/yourcustomtheme/template/checkout** path. If yes, start making changes to customize it.
- If no, copy the **`success.phtml`** file from
  **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout** folder and paste
  it into your theme to customize it.

**Note:** The problem is that when you modify any information on this page, you will want to preview what the results look like, you can't refresh the checkout success page, because a refresh of that page will clean the session and redirect you back to an empty shopping cart page. In other words, every time you make a change to the success-template, you would need to create a new order to preview the result.
To allow success page to stay after refreshing the page, you can temporarily by editing:

> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

file and comment $session->clear(); line.

After commenting out the line should look like:

> //$session->clear();

Remember to roll back your changes after completing the customization in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Copy success.phtml file from `base/default/template/checkout/` directory and paste in `your-package/your-theme-name/template/checkout/` directory structure of your theme. Here you can change text whatever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check first if you have this file in  `app/design/frontend/{current-package}/{your-theme}/template/checkout/success.phtml` and add your text.
2. If you dont find it in your current theme, copy it

from :

`app/design/frontend/{your-package}/default/template/checkout/success.phtml`

to :

`app/design/frontend/{your-package}/{current-theme}/template/checkout/success.phtml`

If you dont find it in `default`, copy it from :

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml`

to:

`app/design/frontend/{your-package}/{your-theme}/template/checkout/success.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2 the success.phtml is at:

```
<magento install dir>\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\success.phtml
```

To allow success page to stay after refreshing the page, you can temporarily edit: `<magento install dir>\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success.php`

comment out `$session->clearQuote();` line as follows:

```
//$session->clearQuote();
```